# Is it possible to make display:table-cell layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

In my code there is a table in which I have divisions which has table row consisting checkboxes horizontally. Here is my sample code, full code is in fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8bitrebellion/BXreg/)

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left" width="65px"><strong> Color: </strong>
        </td>
        <td style="float:left; text-align:left; width:100%">
            <div style="display:table; width:100%">
                <div style="width:100%;display:table-row">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>A</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>B</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>C</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>D</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>E</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>F</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>G</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>H</span> 
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="btn"> <span>I</span> 
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    display: table - cell;
}
```

In pc and tablet view it looks perfect as i want, justified from both left and right side, but in mobile view is it possible to break it into two lines for making it responsive? Please look at fiddle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a media-query to set the divs as `display: block;`. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BXreg/3/)**

Leave the css you have for the larger displays, then use the media-query to target the smaller ones. I would recommend wrapping the label and checkbox together also to keep them from breaking apart:

HTML

```
<div class="table-cell">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    <label class="btn"> <span>A</span> 
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .table, .table-row {
        display: block;
    }
    .table-cell {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

You may need to change the alignment of the labels to your liking.

Comment: see if this helps [**Responsive Tables Demo**](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/)

Comment: @brouxhaha thanks man..it works as i want..just need little bit modification as per requirement..Thanks again.

Comment: @San thanks for suggestion. I have already checked it, but couldn't implement it for above problem. Anyway the answer above worked.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you want:

HTML

```
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left" colspan="9"><strong> Color: </strong>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>A</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>B</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>C</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>D</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>E</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>F</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>G</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>H</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label class="btn"> <span>I</span> 
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
}
.table caption {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.table thead {
    background-color: #444;
}
.table thead tr th {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.table thead tr th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.table tbody {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.table tbody tr td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.table tbody tr td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .table tbody {
        border: 0;
    }
    .table tbody tr {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    }
    .table tbody td {
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 13px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }
    .table tbody td:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    .table tbody td:before {
        content: attr(data-label);
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a media query for phones and tablets min-width 320 to max width 767

Basically, turn the table from desktop viewing

[image]

to phone/tablet viewing

[image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/loginet/nctzk4f3/3/

Resource: https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=facebook

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a better approach. It will help someone in need, as I've left the IT field itself. Thanks again Adrian.