# Cards with different sizes in Bootstrap 4 card-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to mix card of different sizes within a card-group in Bootstrap 4. I want to have a large card (double width) on the left size, and two smaller cards on the right, with the same height of all three.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card col-md-6">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the intention is that card groups are equal width and height(http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#groups), but you could override the default Bootstrap behavior to make it work like this..

```
.card-group [class*='col-'] {
  float:none;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/4WVwRBTyTP

Note: Wildcard CSS selectors like this are slow. It would be better to add a special CSS class to override the Bootstrap `float:left` behavior of the columns in your `card-group`

**UPDATE**

Now that BS4 has flexbox, the extra CSS is no longer required. Just make the `card-group` and `row` the same div, and then use `col-*` as normal to set width. However, using `card-group` will prevent responsive column wrapping.

http://www.codeply.com/go/jzIcjyg6Xa

Answer (score 8):

The Bootstrap 4.1 documentation for [card layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-groups) currently states:

> For the time being, **these layout options are not yet responsive.**

However, as [Zim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35787656/2394348) pointed out, card-groups are now flexbox.  Therefore, you can also override the `flex-grow` style to set relative card sizes.

```
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card" style="flex-grow: 2">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/0pTTyerSlr)

Answer (score -3):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627731/1596547, as already explained by @Skelly the predefined grid classes (`col-md-*`) do not only set the `width` by also a `float`.

Instead of using the grid classes you can also apply the `width` directly:

```
    <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card" style="width:50%;">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
            <p class="card-text">More text 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Text 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```