# How to to combine card-deck with set width cards?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using flex-mode and I would like a 'deck' of 'cards' that all have the same height and width, and the width to be consistent and based on different breakpoints. I have not found a way to do this, though. Whenever I add a `card-deck` class around a group of cards, they ignore any width set, whether with `col-*` classes or by setting a specific width on them.

This is the hierarchy I was trying to make work:
`.row>.card-deck-wrapper>.card-deck>(.col-md-3>.card>.card-block)*4`

And [here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/thedamon/pen/jqVaex) with what I was attempting to make work

Comment: The codepen doesn't look like it's using flexbox mode

Comment: hmm.. i'm not sure how to make it do so. :/

Comment: Fork this [Bootstrap 4 SASS flexbox enabled Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/YFFFWHVoRB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `card-group` and `card-desk` both use `display: table` (or `display:flex` when `$enable-flex` is set to `true`), so you should not wrap your cell into `col-*` classes to set their width. The `col-*` classes not only set the width but also `float: left`, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804749/1596547

For `display: table` the widths are is the result of the automatic table layout algorithm as implemented by the browser, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130851/1596547.

For `display:flex` you can set the `flex-basis` to a fixed width (with both `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` set to `0`) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794791/1596547