# bootstrap 4 card-deck containing cards with different width

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a `card-deck` in bootstrap 4 which contain cards with different width.

For single cards you do the following to change the width (or use class `w-25`, `w-50` or `w-75` if the 25%, 50% or 75% width fit your needs):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card" style="width: 30%">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card" style="width: 70%">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

For a `card-deck` containing cards with equal width you do this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h1>Card Deck with equal width</h1>
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

</div>
```

To have a `card-deck` containing cards with different width I tried this (**without success**):
*Note: The cards are displayed with equal width even that they have different width...*

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card" style="width: 30%">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 70%">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so obviously I'm doing something wrong here (or bootstrap 4 is not supporting this). any suggestions how to use a `card-deck` containing cards with different width?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated [in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-decks), the `card-deck` is **equal width cards**. If you want different width wrap the cards in the Bootstrap grid...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/8qpkLw5Dfv

**Or**, use custom CSS to set the flex basis and max-width of the card-deck cards...

```
.card-deck .cw-30 {
    flex: 1 0 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.card-deck .cw-70 {
    flex: 1 0 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/JiAEZdT0Ob

---

Related: [Cards with different sizes in Bootstrap 4 card-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785410/cards-with-different-sizes-in-bootstrap-4-card-group)

Comment: thanks. yes, I saw the **equal width cards**, but then I also saw the sizing chapter (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/) an thought this might work...