# Why does bootstrap handle col spacing differently depending on num of cols?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<br>
<h6>
This row/deck contains two elements. You can see that even with col-md-4 it spans more than 2/3 of the width.
</h6>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">

      </div>
      <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <br><br>
  <h6>
This row/deck contains three elements. You can see that each card spaces 1/3 of the width as expected.
</h6>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">

      </div>
      <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">

      </div>
            <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9e85Lb0y/

In this example there are two flex-rows each containing a card deck. The first deck has 2 cards and the second deck has 3 cards. All of the cards are identical. Why is it that the top row has wider cards? I would have expected the top row to have the same widths as the bottom row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns aren't meant to be inside card-deck. They're only supposed to be contained in `.row`. The cards would go inside the columns.

From the Bootstrap docs...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns... In a grid layout, content must be
>   placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of
>   rows."

If you're trying to set widths for the cards in card-decks, see:

[Bootstrap 4 card-deck with number of columns based on viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430816/bootstrap-4-card-deck-with-number-of-columns-based-on-viewport/36431664#36431664), ***or***
[bootstrap 4 card-deck containing cards with different width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610770/bootstrap-4-card-deck-containing-cards-with-different-width/51611040#51611040)

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

Use `flex-row` and `col-*` to explicitly specify widths. Use `card-deck` and `card` to create evenly sized blocks. Avoid mixing the two, they are not designed for use together straight out of the box.

**Long Answer**

The issue here is most likely caused by the mixture of both the `flex-row` and `card-deck` classes. While both offer very similar functionality, there are some key differences which separate how they behave.

The `card-deck` class simply guarantees that any immediate elements with the `card` class are all the same width as one another.

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Every `<div class="card"></div>` will now become a uniform width. They are **not** guaranteed to fill the whole of their parent container. The `card` class also applies left and right margins of 15px to keep them separated.

```
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <!-- 1/3 Width Column -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <!-- 1/3 Width Column -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <!-- 1/3 Width Column -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The `flex-row` and `col-*` classes on the other hand allow you to create columns of specific size. Each `col-*` class simply applies a width to the element, the onus is on you to make sure your content will fit appropriately at each breakpoint. `col`'s **SHOULD NOT** have any margins applied as CSS width declarations do not account for margins.

Comment: Thank you for your response and further explanation!